# Syntax highlighting in blog like in Sublime Text 2

Tags: django, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have blog and I want to show codes on the sublimetext editor like that also I want to choice language and it changes color according to the language.

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ExportHtml](https://github.com/facelessuser/ExportHtml) sublime plugin to export syntax highlighted code to html and paste it in your blog.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps take a look at:
http://code.google.com/p/django-syntax-highlight/

It is not 'embedding SublimeText' as per your question, but seems to provide a library that provides some decent syntax highlighting functionality.  It uses http://pygments.org/

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text 2 is not a Javascript editor - you cannot embed it in webpages.

**For edit - what you can embed:**

ACE http://ace.ajax.org/

And some more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors

**For view - syntax hihglighting**

Use Google code prettify http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/